# Opencv how to print the total number of success when extract video to image?

Tags: opencv

I want to print the total number of success at the end of extracting images. For example
print("Total frames: " ,x)

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('car.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file

  count += 1
```

Comment: you can check with an if case, like `if(success) count++`

Comment: I tried that and I got invalid syntax at "+"

Comment: its cos of python sytax, use   count =  count +1 is better

Comment: Use cv2. Puttext()